# In prolog how do you represent state transitions and actions performed by objects?

Tags: algorithm, search, prolog, logic, artificial-intelligence

I have a problem domain consisting of several city state nodes and paths indicating the cost association between places/cities, also the agent is a chopper which can fly from one city to the next.  The scenario problem is for a chopper to take off from one city and land at another.  I know how to implement city states and transitions ok without operations such as takeoff, land etc..., I am just not sure how you represent the agent operations in terms of states or data structures, in order to satisfy an outcome effect such as:- chopper_islanded(true), chopper_at(cityj).

```
% nodes
place(rescueship).
place(citya).
place(cityb).
place(cityc).
place(cityd).
place(citye).
place(cityf).
place(cityg).
place(cityh).
place(cityi).
place(cityj).



% objects
is_chopper(chopper1).

% connections
path(rescueship, citya, 100).
path(rescueship, cityc, 200).
path(rescueship, cityb, 150).
path(cityc, cityd, 110).
path(cityd, citye, 140).
path(cityd, cityf, 100).
path(citya, cityi, 70).
path(cityi, cityg, 130).
path(cityb, cityg, 90).
path(cityi, cityf, 50).
path(citye, cityf, 90).
path(citye, cityj, 50).
path(cityh, cityj, 90).
path(cityi, cityh, 70).
path(citya,cityc,120).
path(citya,cityb,60).


% chopper attributes
chopper_islanded(true).
chopper_islanded(false).

chopper_at(X):- chopper_islanded(true); chopper_islanded(false), place(X), is_chopper(chopper1).

% place states,  G=on ground, A= in air,  v[list of conditions],Ch = chopper
state(v([G,A],P,Ch)):- chopper_islanded(G), chopper_islanded(A), place(P), chopper_at(Ch).


% chopper operations
%takeOff(V1,V2):- place(V1), place(V2).
%takeOff(v([_,A,P),v([false,A],P)).
%land(chopper):- chopper_islanded(false).
%flyto(p1,p2) :- path(p1,p2,_), chopper_islanded(false).

% tried many attempts to implement operations but couldn't understand how to represent an action

connected(P1,P2,C):- path(P1,P2,C) ; path(P2,P1,C).
transition(S1,S2,C) :- connected(S1,S2,C).


initial(rescueship).
goal(cityj).


%  breadth first search uses an initialised state and a goal state which has been omitted for clarity.
bfgs(P)
```

To solve the route I use a breadth first search algorithm which works ok without any chopper operations, it finds the quickest route approximately and returns the list of travelled nodes.  My biggest issue is how does one represent actions that the chopper does in order to achieve a certain state, and what data structure is best to use for this?  sorry if the code is a mess! I have been stumped trying to figure out the semantics, so I haven't omitted my mistakes to demonstrate to others that I have tried at least.

Answer (score 3):

Think in terms of *relations* between actions and states.

First describe what an action in a specific state of the chopper leads to. For example:

```
action_state0_state(take_off, landed, flying).
action_state0_state(land, flying, landed).
action_state0_state(crash, flying, crashed).
action_state0_state(repair, crashed, landed).
```

Using just these simple definitions, you can already reason about a list of actions and the eventual state of the chopper that starts - for example - in landed position:

```
?- length(As, _), foldl(action_state0_state, As, landed, S).
As = [],
S = landed
As = [take_off],
S = flying
As = [take_off, land],
S = landed
As = [take_off, crash],
S = crashed
As = [take_off, land, take_off],
S = flying
As = [take_off, crash, repair],
S = landed .
```

A *list* of actions seems an appropriate data structure in this case, since the empty list makes sense, the number of elements is not known in advance etc.

Comment: Ah I have not seen foldl/4 before, so I need to store combinations of actions/effects into a list, would that mean though I would have to have city states in each combination as a separate list, if so it may require some tricky recursion to specify all states.

Comment: Logically, you only really need to store the actions, since the effects can always be computed from the actions. Higher-order predicates like `maplist/3`, `foldl/4` will help you to make the code more readable by keeping it more compact and avoiding trivial explicit recursions. You will have to let us know more about the precise use case you are trying to solve. From what you have written so far, a list of `City-Actions` pairs sounds like a useful way to represent which actions were performed by the chopper at a given city. Like `[city1-[land,take_off],city2-[land,take_off], ...]` etc.